# Why is a black iPhone 4S is shown as white in iTunes?

Tags: iphone

I've recently got a new **black** iPhone 4S, but in iTunes and Xcode organizer it is shown as **white** (see screenshots below).

I purchased this new within the UK (model MD239B), but I'm not sure if it was refurbished. [The search request](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.kbase.search&locale=en_GB&q=MD239B) says it is a white one. Could it possibly be a refurbished device? I've checked the serial number on support.apple.com, there is no single word similar to 'refurbished'.

[image]

Comment: Did you buy it in the store? Or somewhere second hand?

Comment: It is brand new

Comment: I've seen this on occasion where the serial number look up table doesn't match reality. It's more worrisome when your Mac shows up as the wrong model, but usually it gets corrected if enough devices were categorized incorrectly. Just call Apple support and have them verify your IMEI/Serial Number match their records and you should be good to go.

Comment: #FirstWorldProblems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes deduces the color of the iPhone from the serial number he finds on the logic board.  For example:

```
MD269LL   = Black AT&T 64GB 4S  
MD271LL   = White AT&T 64GB 4S  
MD277LL/A = White Verizon 16GB 4S
...
```

So, check your model number and look it up to make sure you've got a black one.

[image]

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.kbase.search&locale=en_GB&q=MD239B The search says it is a white one. Could it possibly be a refurbished device? I've checked the serial on support.apple.com, there is no single word like refurbished.

Comment: There you have your answer. The model number tells iTunes it's a white one, so iTunes displays it as a white one.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a classic mixup. Apple and AT&T/Verizon often have iPhone roaming around between them based on bad or returned devices and other reasons.

Just make sure that the IMEI number on your phone is the same as that associated with your account. I faced a problem where the AT&T folk told me that the IMEI I told them from my iPhone was a fake!

So, just make sure that your Wireless provider (AT&T or Verizon) are aware of the phone and the IMEI and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but mine is neverlock from UK